# App crashes after deleting reordered UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to allow a UITableView to be re-ordered by a user and also delete it's cells.
Reordering works fine. And deleting works fine too if the cells are not yet reordered. However, if I reorder the cells using moveRowAtIndexPath and delete one cell, the wrong cell/data is being deleted. Say that I have data `A,B,C` reordered to become `A,C,B`. If I delete "C" the result will be `A,C` instead of `A,B`. I am using an NSMutableArray to get the data from and set to the UITableView.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
    MyObject *obj = [myArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [myArray removeObject:obj];
    [myArray insertObject:obj atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}
```

and deleting looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Change 'MyObject *track = ...' to 'MyObject * obj = ...' Is it a typo?

Comment: Just like I said, if I reorder A,B,C to A,C,B and delete C, the result is A,C instead of A,B. And then after deleting B, I get:
'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: @Avt yes sorry it was a typo.

Comment: @Fogmeister If I reorder A,B,C to A,C,B and delete C, the result is A,C instead of A,B. And then after deleting B, I get: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Also I would only delete the object from the datasource once you've called [tableView endUpdates];

Comment: @jeraldo  you have 'endUpdates' but you do not have 'beginUpdates'. A typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code looks good. I think issue could be somewhere else. There is a chance that you can fix it replacing

```
[myArray removeObject:obj];
```

with

```
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
```

Comment: Seems like this gave me the clue that I am doing something wrong. I am using a custom method on my object using removeObject, creating a new method for removing the object using the index did it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also update the datasource correctly.

Try this handy [category.](http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/11/15/moving-objects-within-an-nsmutablearray/)..

```
@interface NSMutableArray (MoveArray)

- (void)moveObjectFromIndex:(NSUInteger)from toIndex:(NSUInteger)to;

@end

- (void)moveObjectFromIndex:(NSUInteger)from toIndex:(NSUInteger)to
    {
        if (to != from) {
            id obj = [self objectAtIndex:from];
            [self removeObjectAtIndex:from];
            if (to >= [self count]) {
                [self addObject:obj];
            } else {
                [self insertObject:obj atIndex:to];
            }
        }
    }
    @end
```

Comment: Doesn't [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row] inside moveRowAtIndexPath already do that?